# regexp: refer to alternation of groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace such string

```
let s = `
~"blah~
~'blah"~
~'blah'~
~blah"~
=blah"=
=blah'=`
```

you can get my intention from this workable code

```
s = s.replace(/(=|~)('|")(.*?)\1/g, `<code>$2$3</code>`)
     .replace(/(=|~)(.*?)('|")\1/g, `<code>$2$3</code>`)
```

now `s` is

```
<code>"blah</code>
<code>'blah"</code>
<code>'blah'</code>
<code>blah"</code>
<code>blah"</code>
<code>blah'</code>
```

My question is how to achieve that within one `replace` function, like:

```
s = s.replace(/(=|~)(('|")(.*?)|(.*?)('|"))\1/g, `<code>${$3 || $5}${$4 || $6}</code>`)
// extra line to push annoying scroll bar down
```

this code doesn't work ofc. more specifically, how to refer to ... oh my god I just realized that I can just refer the whole group like below to satisfy my requirement

```
s = s.replace(/(=|~)(('|")(.*?)|(.*?)('|"))\1/g, `<code>$2</code>`)
```

However, since the question is half done, and I still curious about how to refer to `$3 or $5`, string way, not the callback way.

Or I've stepped into an impasse.

Comment: I don't understand the question - it sounds like your code works already? Can you edit out the question that you solved and elaborate on what the real problem is? `$3` will refer to the 3rd capture group, similarly with `$5`

Comment: @CertainPerformance  `$3` and `$5` are in an alternation group, so they are mutually exclusive. I want to refer to the one matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A capture group that doesn't get matched, when included in the second callback to a `.replace`, will result in an empty string. So, if group 3 and 5 are mutually exclusive, and you want to refer to *either* group 3 or group 5, whichever was matched, you can just write `$3$5` - the one which was *not* matched will simply result in the empty string (so it won't cause any issues in the result).

```js
let s = `
~"blah~
~'blah"~
~'blah'~
~blah"~
=blah"=
=blah'=`;


const replaced = s.replace(
  /(=|~)(('|")(.*?)|(.*?)('|"))\1/g,
  `<code>$2 and group 3 or 5 is [$3$5]</code>`
);
console.log(replaced);
```

Note that in this case it would make more sense to use non-capturing groups rather than capturing groups when you don't want to save that resulting group for something, and it would make more sense to use a character set than alternating inside a group:

```js
let s = `
~"blah~
~'blah"~
~'blah'~
~blah"~
=blah"=
=blah'=`;


const replaced = s.replace(
  /([=~])((['"]).*?|(.*?)['"])\1/g,
  `<code>$2 and group 3 or 4 is [$3$4]</code>`
);
console.log(replaced);
```

Note that groups 3 and 5 in your original code refer to the quote (in the first alternation) and the text (in the second alternation), which seems a bit odd. Perhaps you wanted the text in both:

```js
let s = `
~"blah~
~'blah"~
~'blah'~
~blah"~
=blah"=
=blah'=`;


const replaced = s.replace(
  /([=~])(['"](.*?)|(.*?)['"])\1/g,
  `<code>$2 and group 3 or 4 is [$3$4]</code>`
);
console.log(replaced);
```